# How to avoid loading node_modules and .ts files on production mode in angular 4 with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, node-modules

My project is built on angular 4 over asp.net mvc(VS2017). While on the production mode all *.ts file and node modules are loading to browser , How do i avoid loading *.ts files and node_module folder to browser on final release.

Comment: PLS can u also answer my question [my question p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223021/i-want-to-order-my-post-within-div)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build the angular app using `ng build --prod`.

---

This will compile the application and compress and minify all the files. In fact, the `.ts` files are converted to `.js` files at this point of time.

`ng build --prod` employs the AOT (Ahead of Time) technique, which means before loading the app, it is already compiled way ahead of time.

`ng serve` employs the JIT (Just in Time) technique where the browser compiles the `.ts` files at the run time.

---

For more information about certain advantages / steps that Angular CLI takes while building, please refer to the following URL:-

> https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod

For further information about the Angular compiler and various options available for compiling, you may also refer to the below post:-

> https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler